# Can I use update_all on array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have list of comments in one array. Can I use update_all on array ?

```
comments = Comments.find(:all,:conditions => ["test is not null"]) 

comments.update_all(:test => nil)
```

Comment: You can use `Comments.update_all("test = NULL", "test is not null")` instead

Comment: Let me ask this really quick - have you tried it?  Rails console is a great tool for trying this sort of thing out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot use `update_all` with arrays, only with scopes. `find` or `all` (in older version of Rails) return an array. Instead:

```
comments = Comments.scoped(:conditions => "test IS NOT NULL")
comments.update_all(:test => nil)
```

On modern versions of Ruby/ActiveRecord, you can write:

```
Comments.where.not(test: nil).update_all(test: nil)
```

Answer (score 4):

update_all is a method provided by ActiveRecord, and what you have is an Array, you have two options either use ActiveRecord through Comments (will update database) or map the array, changing only the objets in memory and not modifying the database:

```
comments = Comments.update_all({:test => nil}, 'test IS NOT NULL')
```

or

```
comments = Comments.find(:all,:conditions => ["test is not null"])
comments.map! { |c| c.test = nil unless c.test}
```

EDIT: Error in the second example, is c.test not c

Comment: Your second example doesn't actually save the changes to the database (it would need a `c.save` or something), and you're setting the whole comment to `nil`, not just `c.test`.

Comment: I fixed the problem with setting the whole comment, about not saving the changes in the database, it was already in the text of my answer, the question doesn't say if the changes are supposed to be applied to database or only to the array... thats why I gave two solutions